# how I can change the voice synthesizer gender and age in C#?

Tags: c#, speech, synthesizer

I would like to change the gender and age of the voice of `System.Speech` in c#. For example, a girl of 10 years but can not find any simple example to help me adjust the parameters.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, check which voices you have installed by enumerating the [`GetInstalledVoices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.getinstalledvoices.aspx) method of the [`SpeechSynthesizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596245) class, and then use [`SelectVoiceByHints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586877) to select one of them:

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    // show installed voices
    foreach (var v in synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices().Select(v => v.VoiceInfo))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Gender:{1}, Age:{2}",
          v.Description, v.Gender, v.Age);
    }

    // select male senior (if it exists)
    synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Senior);

    // select audio device
    synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    // build and speak a prompt
    PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
    builder.AppendText("Found this on Stack Overflow.");
    synthesizer.Speak(builder);
}
```

Comment: If speaker is a woman yet, means that I dont have male voice in my system, so I need to download it?

Comment: @Pablo: that's correct, although, to tell you the truth, I have no clue where to download them from. [This MSDN page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224) looks like it has some additional voices, but I never used any of them.

Comment: Ok, change voice properties is just a question I had time ago, because I wanna know more about speech namespace. I will go to find a little girl voice if really exist hahah
thanks again

Answer (score 13):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voiceage.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voicegender.aspx

Did you take a look at this ?

Comment: Why [StackOverFlow](http://http://stackoverflow.com) doesn't have **LIKE** button ? :)

Comment: I don't know, but it has a [+1] button ! :P

Comment: speaker.(VoiceGender 2, VoiceAge 10);

Comment: Member names are NotSet, Child, Teen, etc..., why did you try "VoiceAge 10" ?

Comment: because I am a novice...properties, members, class, events, still confusing me a lot

Comment: You should check Groo's answer so, look at how he selected the voice : `synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Senior);`

Comment: What ? _Sorry my english's not well and I don't know what you mean_

Comment: @PabloGonzalez: you probably only have a single voice installed ("Microsoft Anna", a female adult).

Comment: You need to check if the voice you need is installed. Look at Groo's Answer, he gave you all the code to do what you need to do. :)

Answer (score 4):

first you need to intialise the reference speech using the add reference.

then create an event handler for the speak started then you can edit the paramemters inside that handler.

in the handler is where you can change the voice and age using the

```
synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male , VoiceAge.Adult);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis; // first import this package

    namespace textToSpeech
    {
        public partial class home : Form
        {
            public string s = "pran"; // storing string (pran) to s

            private void home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    speech(s); // calling the function with a string argument
                }

            private void speech(string args) // defining the function which will accept a string parameter
                {
                    SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                    synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male , VoiceAge.Adult); // to change VoiceGender and VoiceAge check out those links below
                    synthesizer.Volume = 100;  // (0 - 100)
                    synthesizer.Rate = 0;     // (-10 - 10)
                    // Synchronous
                    synthesizer.Speak("Now I'm speaking, no other function'll work");
                    // Asynchronous
                    synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Welcome" + args); // here args = pran
                }       
         }
    }
```

- It'll be better choice to use "SpeakAsync" because when "Speak" function is executing/running none of other function will work until it finishes it's work (personally recommended)

[Change VoiceGender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voicegender.aspx)
[Change VoiceAge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voiceage.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

These age and gender is actually of no use. If you have many voices installed in your windows, then you may call specific voices by these parameters. Otherwise, its simply fake!