# Change gender of text-to-speech voice

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

I want to make a text to speech program for my interactive training set. I used the `System.Speech` library, but the voice is always female. I would like some sentences to be read with a male voice, and some to be read by a female voice. (These two voices are the only ones I need.)

I'm using Windows 8 Pro and Visual Studio 2010. I can see only one voice pack, the Microsoft Zira Desktop.

My code is as follows. How can I configure the use of a male voice?

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
synth.Rate = 1;
synth.Volume = 100;
synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male,VoiceAge.Adult);
synth.SpeakAsync(label18.Text);
```

Comment: Perhaps other voices need to be installed on the system in question?

Comment: Have you tried the `SelectVoice` method call, which accepts a VoiceGender argument string? Or have you verified by calling `GetInstalledVoices` that there are voices to match your specified hints? What Culture are you using?

Comment: i tried GetInstalledVoices with foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices()) and it showed only Microsoft Zira, then i've 2 problem now :)
1) how can i install microsoft david desktop
2) if i will succeed install, how the program will run another pc which without microsoft david?

sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 6):

You first need to know which voices are installed, you can do this by GetInstalledVoices method of SpeechSynthesizer class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.getinstalledvoices.aspx

Once you're sure that you've got a male voice installed, then you can simply switch by SelectVoiceByHints
See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586877

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    // show installed voices
    foreach (var v in synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices().Select(v => v.VoiceInfo))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Gender:{1}, Age:{2}",
          v.Description, v.Gender, v.Age);
    }

    // select male senior (if it exists)
    synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Senior);

    // select audio device
    synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    // build and speak a prompt
    PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
    builder.AppendText("Found this on Stack Overflow.");
    synthesizer.Speak(builder);
}
```

See this for further explanation:
[how I can change the voice synthesizer gender and age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881370/how-i-can-change-the-voice-synthesizer-gender-and-age-in-c)