# c# and text to speech

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

Using the code:

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
synth.Rate = 0;
synth.Speak(Line);
```

How do I say things and make the voice sound more epic?

Comment: things such as lower voice. Great to narrate an RPG.

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881370/how-i-can-change-the-voice-synthesizer-gender-and-age-in-c, keep in mind that the voices are part of windows, not your program. So you can only use what is installed on the machine.

Comment: Thanks mate. Is there a way to lower the voice?

Comment: I don't think you can alter the voice, you can only use a different voice.

Comment: synth.Speak(Line + SpeechBuilder(MorganFreeman, synth.Audio);

Answer (score 0):

The full documentation available here about [SpeechSynthesizer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice(v=office.14).aspx)

You can check the Installed voices and choose the appropriate ones.,

```
    foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
    {
         VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;
         Console.WriteLine(" Voice Name: " + info.Name);
    }
```

Setting / Changing the voice [Gender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voicegender.aspx) and [Age](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voiceage.aspx) might help,

```
synthesizer.Volume = 100; // This might helps to change Voice bit lower and upper rates.
synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Senior);
```

***Note:*** Those voice enumerations must be installed in your machine.