# How I can change the voice synthesizer gender and age in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, speech, c#-to-vb.net, speech-synthesis

I am a novice in programming. I would like to change the gender and age of the voice of System. Speech in VB.NET. Like this question 
[How I can change the voice synthesizer gender and age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881370/how-i-can-change-the-voice-synthesizer-gender-and-age-in-c)

So, I am confused how to declare this code to VB.NET

```
foreach (var v in synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices().Select(v => v.VoiceInfo))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Gender:{1}, Age:{2}",
          v.Description, v.Gender, v.Age);
    }
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Getting a choice in voices requires money, your machine has only one.  Shopping questions are not on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each v As var In synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices().[Select](Function(v) v.VoiceInfo)
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Gender:{1}, Age:{2}", v.Description, v.Gender, v.Age)
Next
```

But this code only get the list of installed voices. To set the voice for your syntesizer you need to make following:

```
synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult);
```

here is detailed information about this (including VB.NET): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586877
Here is an example of simple code on VB: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/courses/spsci/compmeth/speech/synthesis.html

Comment: Thanks that may help me. but I am still confused with this        synthesizer.SpeakAsync(Label1.Text)
How to change to another voices

Comment: I used synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Teen) but not work for me

Comment: update your post with full code that you're using, please