# Voice age of System.Speech.Synthesis

Tags: c#, sdk, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I want to use  `System.Speech.Synthesis` for a winform desktop app executable assembly.

I want to change the [voice age](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voiceage.aspx) or use a [neutral gender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.voicegender.aspx), but right now I can change only the gender (female and male).

I've downloaded [MSSpeech_SR_en-US_TELE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224) and [x64_SpeechPlatformRuntime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=27225)  as my system is x64 and I've installed both.

I did not install Microsoft Speech Platform (SDK) [x64_MicrosoftSpeechPlatformSDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226)   because it is already installed. Maybe I need to repair it with above installs again or I need something else, because nothing changes:

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    foreach (var v in synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices().Select(v => v.VoiceInfo))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Gender:{1}, Age:{2}", v.Description, v.Gender, v.Age);
    }

    synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Child);

    synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
    builder.AppendText("Found this on Stack Overflow.");
    synthesizer.Speak(builder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this similar question if the enum doesn't exist for the age or gender it means you will have to download it. How/where you download it from is another question..

[how I can change the voice synthesizer gender and age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881370/how-i-can-change-the-voice-synthesizer-gender-and-age-in-c)

Comment: hello, I've updated my question by following the instructions for your link